How to add/retrieve images to/from the ContentNote via REST APIs?
Context/Scenario:
There is an integration with external system which supports display of notes (enhanced notes) and let's users create notes. I am able to create the Salesforce Notes by creating ContentNote record via REST apis and then linking it to desired record via ContentDocumentLink. However, I am not sure how to create a ContentNote which has some image in it. I did not find any documentation about it.
If there is any documentation which details out how to create a ContentNote which has few images, it would be really appreciated.
So far this is what I tried. I used salesforce standard UI and created a note and added an image. Then fetched details via REST call and got below response
<p>Here is the attached image.</p><p><img src="https://sflab-dev-ed.file.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=0688W000013ybieQAA&amp;feoid=ContentBody&amp;refid=0EM8W00000EFYKB" alt="God.JPG"></img></p><p>Above is the attached image.</p><p><br></p>

This tells me that salesforce uploads the image internally and adds the path to the body.  If I have to do the same via REST then I would need to create image first. I did not find any api which let's me create/upload an image to salesforce which can be accessed with the url like /servlet/rtaImage?eid=&feoid=&refid=.
To summarize I have below queries:

Is it possible to create ContentNote along with images by external system (e.g. like using REST apis)?
If yes, how that would look like ? I assume first I need to create/upload image and add image path in ContentNote body.
How to access the image which gets stored by salesforce in the format "https://sflab-dev-ed.file.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=0688W000013ybieQAA&feoid=ContentBody&refid=0EM8W00000EFYKB" ? I tried to make simple REST api call to this end point (with access token), but it simply resulted in html content without any image/binary data.
Salesforce has documented about how to retrieve the image which is uploaded to RichText area, but I did not see any documentation which talks about accessing images from the ContentNote.

